# How can two PsychoPy .psydat files be combined into a .csv I can import into R?

Tags: psychopy

While running an experiment I made an error. If PsychoPy has correct participant codes, then the two conditions are combined into one .csv per session. (If not two .psydat files are created.) I know that .psydat is a format which contains more information than the csv format I need, but I'm not sure how to access the information which is there so it can be added to my dataframe and analysed in R. For example, I need to combine the data in MA22BI1.psydat and MAMA22BI1.psydat into MA22BI1.csv. I couldn't find anything remotely related in the PsychoPy forum. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: You can regenerate a .csv file from a .psydat file using the code supplied here: https://www.psychopy.org/general/dataOutputs.html. But that will still leave you with two .csv files. Combining .csv files into a single data frame in R is straightforward, though, so it's not clear exactly what your question is?

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate a .csv file from a .psydat file using the code supplied here: psychopy.org/general/dataOutputs.html.